# What is the easiest way for me to recover all my Whatsapp messages?

Tags: data-recovery, whatsapp-messenger

I recently got a new phone and changed my whatsapp number. However, while I was added to all previous chat groups in my new phone, I couldn't see the chat history. Since I changed my whatsapp number on my old phone as well, I no longer have the chat history for my old number.

What is the easiest way for me to restore all my messages?

I followed this link: https://geeknizer.com/read-extract-whatsapp-messages-android-iphone-blackberry/ which i got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15427040/16197225

I managed to find an encrypted file called msgstore.db on my old android. However, this solution doesn't work for me as I don't have a paid ActiveState subscription and thus can only create public projects, but due to privacy concerns, I would prefer to avoid this method.

Also, I just thought of another question: Is it possible to use one whatsapp account for two phones?

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. ActiveState provides lots of products, neither of which should be required for whatever you are trying to do. Your Stack Overflow link goes to a question with lots of answers. Please link to the answer you are trying to work with.

Comment: You can run Python programs on your own system, you don't need any subscription. According to the answers to the linked SO question you might get problems with improved encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Login back on your old device and it will detect a local backup
restore the backup then make a google drive chat backup with your email address in whatsapp settings and now go to the new device and make sure to delete whatsapp and all of its data and download it again then login and restore the data from drive :)